# Can $\int t^3(25+81t^2)^{5/2} dt$ be solved through Trigo Substitution of integrals?

Tags: integration

> Can $\int t^3(25+81t^2)^{5/2} dt$ be solved through Trigo Substitution of integrals?

This is a trigo substitution practice problem. I checked integral online calculator from wolfram alpha and it tells me to do normal $u$ substitutuon. However I attempted trigo substitution:

Let $t= \frac{5}{9} \tan \theta$,

$dt= \frac{5}{9} \sec^2 \theta d\theta$

Eliminating the roots:

$(\sqrt{25+81t^2})^5+ = (\sqrt{25+25 \tan^2 \theta})^5 = (5 \sec^2 \theta )^5 = 3125 \sec^5 \theta $

Substituting:

$\int t^3(25+81t^2)^{5/2} dt = \int (\frac{125}{729} \tan^3 \theta)(3125 \sec^5 \theta) (\frac{5}{9} \sec^2 \theta d\theta)$

But now, when I key in the above expression into the online integral calculator, I get a different answer. Where have I went wrong in this trigo substitution method?

Comment: Yes, it can be done in the way you propose.  I would suggest that you keep working until you have a final answer, and then check it by calculating its derivative with an online calculator.  Otherwise, it may be that you have two different answers which are both correct (and which are non-obviously equal to each other up to a $+C$).

Comment: I prefer  $t = \frac{5}{9}  \sinh w $  which gives $dt = \frac{5}{9}  \cosh w \; \; dw $

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-The binomial integrals of Chebyshev $\int t^m(a+bt^n)^pdt$ **are non integrables by elementary methods excepting the three following cases**:

$(1)$ when $p$ is integer you make $t=x^r$ where $r$ is the m.c.m.of denominators of the fractions $m$ and $n$.

$(2)$ When $\dfrac{m+1}{n}$ is an integer you make $a+bt^n=x^s$ where $s$ is the denominator of the fraction $p$.

$(3)$ When $\dfrac{m+1}{n}+1$ is an integer you make $a+bt^n=x^st^n$ or $a+bt^{-n}=x^s$ where $s$ is the denominator of the fraction $p$

Your integral is an example of the second case so you can solve the problem by the indicated elementary change of variables.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you "went wrong" anywhere, but here is a simpler substitution:
$$s:=25+81t^2,\quad\mathrm ds=162\,t\,\mathrm dt.$$
$$\begin{align}\int(25+81t^2)^{5/2}t^3\,\mathrm dt&=\int s^{5/2}\frac{s-25}{81}\frac{\mathrm ds}{162}\\
&=\left[\frac{s^{7/2}}{6561}\left(\frac s9-\frac{25}7\right)\right]\\
&=\left[\frac{(25+81t^2)^{7/2}}{6561}\left(\frac{567t^2-50}{63}\right)\right].
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

The integral may be evaluated directly

\begin{align}
&\int t^3(25+81t^2)^{5/2} dt\\
=& \ \frac1{81}\int \left[(25+81t^2)^{7/2}-25(25+81t^2)^{5/2} \right]t\ dt\\
=&\ \frac1{81^2}\left[\frac19(25+81t^2)^{9/2}
-\frac{25}7(25+81t^2)^{7/2}\right]+C
\end{align}